# CSV uploading as Multipart file throws "Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items error in Spring API

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am trying to upload a CSV file to do some operation. I am using OpenCSV 5.7.1 version to handle CSV file.
As of now, I was just simply exploring the functionalities, i.e one API to upload file and then reading the file if it is able to fetch the data or not.

Controller Class:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> processCsvUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("request") String uploadRequest) {
  //call service method
}
```

Service Class:

```java
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MvAppException();
        }
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(1).build();
        try {
            List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
            for (String[] arr : rows) {
                for (String temp : arr)
                    System.out.print(temp + ", ");
                System.out.println("");
            }
        } catch (IOException | CsvException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MvAppException();
        }
```

However after sending response, it is posting these logs:

```java
2023-04-30 22:55:34.019  WARN 20072 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.m.s.StandardServletMultipartResolver : Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items

java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\Nayan-J\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.193216173997807150\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_2c1409b9_6b24_4c83_99e0_32248a854b2c_00000017.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1250) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1107) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at com.nayanj.mamavidyalaya.fitlerninterceptors.RequestLoggerInterceptor.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerInterceptor.java:58) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at com.nayanj.mamavidyalaya.fitlerninterceptors.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:75) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\Nayan-J\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.193216173997807150\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_2c1409b9_6b24_4c83_99e0_32248a854b2c_00000017.tmp
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

There is no good resource I could find to resolve this issue. To add, I am using embedded tomcat as application server. Please help.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? If newer than 2.7.6, does downgrading help? Might be a bug in embedded Tomcat, which was updated in Spring Boot 2.7.7: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.7.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use try with resource, it should fix your issue.

I encountered similar issue today and using try with resource fixed the issue!

For your piece of code, it will look like -

> try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream())) {
> ... }

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strange. This worked!
Can you explain why this works and what was wrong in my code?

Comment: When the try statement ends, the InputStream will automatically close

Answer (score 0):

Convert multipart to File first.

```
private File convertMultipartToFile(MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
    String file = imageFile.getOriginalFilename();
    log.info("File name ==> {}", file);
    assert file != null;
    File convertFile = new File(file);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(convertFile);
    fileOutputStream.write(imageFile.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();
    return convertFile;
}
```

then call the `convertFile.delete()` method after your upload.

Answer (score -1):

use try and catch block for reference check following code
@PostMapping("/post/image/upload/{postId}")
public ResponseEntity uploadPostImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,
@PathVariable Integer postId) {

```
   PostDto postDto=null;
    try {
         postDto= this.postService.getPostById(postId);
       String  fileName= this.fileService.uploadImage(path, image);
         postDto.setImageName(fileName);
        
       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      
    }
   
    PostDto updatedPost= this.postService.updatePost(postDto, postId);
  return new ResponseEntity<PostDto>(updatedPost, HttpStatus.OK);
   
}
```

however error in terminal is visible but image is uploaded in db
.
.
.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\Apunich Bhagwan Hai\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.18372763972742625326\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_2b881de4_e289_4604_bc97_7063aadae178_00000009.tmp
... 14 common frames omitted